# Writing 2 rows to TXT in 1 loop

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable like this:

```
TerminalNo      Payment      ORNO    Time
PHW0501         1,000.00     1       1:05pm
PHW0502         2,000.00     2       1:05pm
PHW0501         3,000.00     3       1:10pm
PHW0502         4,000.00     4       1:10pm
PHW0501         5,000.00     5       1:15pm
PHW0502         6,000.00     6       1:15pm
PHW0501         7,000.00     7       1:20pm
PHW0502         8,000.00     8       1:20pm
```

> Everytime that payment has been made on both Terminal(at the same time
> or not), I want to get the **Payment** for both **TerminalNo** and
> write it on a different **TXT file** with different folder path.

Like this:

```
    FolderPath1/Txt1 
 PHW0501, 1,000.00, 1:05pm, 1

    FolderPath2/Txt2
PHW0502, 2,000.00, 1:05pm, 2
```

I only get this:

```
Folder1/Txt1 = PHW0501, 1,000.00, 1:05pm, 1
```

This is my code:

```
DataRow rw = dtTransaction.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(tt => tt.Field<string>("TerminalNo") == "PHW0501");
DataRow rw2 = dtTransaction.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(tt => tt.Field<string>("TerminalNo") == "PHW0502");
string fileName1 = GeneratedPath1 + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".txt";
string fileName2 = GeneratedPath2 + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".txt";
for (int i = 0; i < dtTransaction.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (rw.ItemArray[4].ToString().Equals("PHW0501"))
    {
        if (dtTransaction.Rows[i]["TerminalNo"].ToString().Equals("PHW0501") && !dtTransaction.Rows[i]["ORNo"].ToString().Equals(""))
        {
            string Time = dtTransaction.Rows[i]["Time"];
            double Payment = -double.Parse(dtTransaction.Rows[i]["Payment"].ToString());
            int ORNo = dtTransaction.Rows[i]["ORNo"].ToString();

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fileName1))
            {
                sw.Write("PHW0501" + ",");
                sw.Write(Payment + ",");
                sw.Write(Time + ",");
                sw.Write(ORNo);
            }   
        }
    }
    if (rw2.ItemArray[4].ToString().Equals("PHW0502"))
    {
        if (dtTransaction.Rows[i]["TerminalNo"].ToString().Equals("PHW0502") && !dtTransaction.Rows[i]["ORNo"].ToString().Equals(""))
        {
            string Time = dtTransaction.Rows[i]["Time"];
            double Payment = double.Parse(dtTransaction.Rows[i]["Payment"].ToString());
            int ORNo = dtTransaction.Rows[i]["ORNo"].ToString();

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fileName2))
            {
                sw.Write("PHW0502" + ",");
                sw.Write(Payment + ",");
                sw.Write(Time + ",");
                sw.Write(ORNo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting non-compiling code? `int ORNo = dtTransaction.Rows[i]["ORNo"].ToString();`

Comment: What types of columns do your DataTable have? All are strings? Why?

Comment: `double Payment` - What a shame! You just lost some money. To work with money, use the `decimal` type.

Comment: It is better to use the `yyyyMMdd` format for the file/directory name. It will allow you to easily sort them by date.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ for grouping.

```
var grouped = dtTransaction.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row["ORNo"].ToString() != "")
    .GroupBy(row => row["TerminalNo"]);

foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    string folder = group.Key.ToString();
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
    string filename = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".txt";
    string path = Path.Combine(folder, filename);

    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in group)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
        }
    }
}
```

Here directories named PHW0501 and PHW0502 will be created. You can add some prefix to them.

Next, in each directory will be created file.

Comma-separated data is entered to the file.

Answer (score 0):

use this code. You have to put after filePath "true" to continue second line.

```
string path =  "PATH TO YOU TEXT FILE WITH FILENAME AND EXTENSION";
using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
     writetext.WriteLine("Language: " + language);
     writetext.WriteLine("Log Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the aswer. But it has to be in a different path and different txt. I already edited my question to be more clear. Thank you